# Почему размер массива ограничен 32 битами?

Tags: c#, .net

Давно интересовал вопрос,  почему managed массив имеет свойство Length типа int (которое отображается в System.Int32). Получается даже работая в 64битной среде мы по прежнему ограничены этим фактом. Вопрос усложняется еще и тем что разрабатывая например интероп с нативным с++ приложением, мы по прежнему ограничены размером managed массива (например размер `std::vector` будет ограничем 64 битами).

Minor note: разумеется авторы библиотеки руководствовались cls compliance, но почему тогда не выбрали платформо зависимый тип чтобы поддерживать большее количество элементов на различных платформах? как можно с этим бороться?

Comment: А причем тут размер и размерность?

Comment: Размер ограничен потому что нет острой необходимости в больших непрерывный массивах. Смысл индекса именно в том чтоб быстро передвигаться по структуре. А размерность системы обусловлена аппаратной необходимостью по большей части.

Comment: Массив по сути - сырой кусок последовательной памяти, при этом с практической точки зрения не особо часто и нужны такие огромные размеры, а во вторых, всё равно полностью такой объём в оперативку не будет помещаться, будет переключение страниц. В общем, я что-то сомневаюсь, что у вас есть реально задача в которой это нужно. Давайте задачу в студию

Comment: @AzizUmarov возможно не совсем правильно написан заголовок, согласен. меня интересовало в частности почему так выбран тип и как с этим бороться (хотел максимально правильно сделать интероп с с++, конечно вероятность того что будет использоваться вектор с 2^32 + 1 элементом крайне мала)

Comment: Бороться с ним не надо. А нужно иметь ввиду и работать. Посмотрите на StringBuilder как пример

Comment: Как бороться - создаёте класс, обьявляете `operator[]` - и ставите в оператор 64-битный индекс. И делаете массив с каким хотите индексом. Мне кажется что для 64-битного индекса надо очень аккуратно с памятью быть.

Comment: @nick_n_a то есть просто сделать обертку над нативным массивом? а если мне надо будет чисто теоретически (пока такую ситуацию не могу представить) из c# большой массив (2^32 +1) обработать и передать в c++?

Comment: Поскольку это разные языки я предполагаю это различные приложения, хотя не обязательно. Передавайте поток а не массив.

Comment: Я думаю такая ситуация не встретится. Такое может встретится или на олимпиаде, или в каких-то учебных краевых задачах, или если вы пишите что-то такое сложное, даже сложно представить что. Например sql-менеджер с возможностью смотреть более 4 млн строк, и то там можно перегрупировать. В видео/аудио задачах это не нужно. Сложно представить ещё задачу где это реально нужно.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element

Comment: Кстати, у вас ЦП сколько гигагерц? Вы просто предствьте, если у вас 1 ГГц, это значит 4 млрд ЦП "переберёт" вхолостую за 4 секунды. Но если на обработку "еденицы данных" понадобится по 100 тактов - это уже будет 400 сек - т.е. почти 5 минут. Учитывая современные скорости работы, вы можете себе представить расчёт который длится час, который ну.. востребован? В обычной жизни нет, такие сложные расчёты происходят или когда видеофайл обрабатывается (но он обрабатывается частями), или когда драйвер СУБД лопатит СУБД (но вы не пишите драйвер СУБД). Или если делают какие-то исследования/соревнования.

Comment: Попробуйте ради интереса создать массив на (2^32-1) под х64 и заполнить его еденицами. Я думаю результат по времени вас удивит.

Comment: @nick_n_a Ну время заполнения такого массива будет менее 8 секунд. Это страшно?

Comment: Обычный пример плохого проектирования, когда особенности реализации стали особенностью интерфейса и теперь у разработчиков связаны руки. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/12221

Answer (score 0):

Есть подозрение, что количество элементов массива не связанно напрямую с ограничениями x32/x64. 2 147 483 647 элемента, тем более, если это элементы стека, а не кучи, несколько избыточно для системы любой разрядности.

Comment: Почему это избыточно? "640 килобайт хватит всем"?

Comment: @MBo, а причем здесь 640 килобайт, и тот факт что если в массиве будут лежать ссылки, то теперь если размер перемножить на 4/8 то там как раз и скорее всего будет упор в ограничение на размер у указателя на 64 битной системе.

Comment: Массивы всегда размещаются в куче.